# Why is the RSA signature result of golang different from that of OpenSSL command?

Tags: go, openssl, rsa, sign

Recently, I encountered RSA signature in a project. I hope an experienced brother could help.

The OpenSSL (version 1.0.2u) command I used:

`echo -n -e "test\n"|openssl dgst -sha256 -sign ./apiclient_key.pem| openssl base64 -A`

The result is as follows

```
pyoBMuN8UqRGLVR7YcQ11yn+dQ9rSU/fB7obQhs27eotvd51q+E8BqxB6AYQDTnlqAQnOiR1rnuxPjlGkAOaPxpCqfhS5VGblh3HuNNHiycdKKa5mM1XyaWROiL7YpyYHRUcblkICW4XEN8v5wyFHxQ+TZfBN8fdqmlLdSczZ66YnIUgaWjBkdC1UH9GqMOQkySaQbgxjh4WhWvVE4umlKz+lAj9OLBhqI/ZXcs6gPFIpyNl8hlMPi6QOxFDSPZmQZl9G7mzx4E0lBoCY5XJtm5VwG3IYTryKZvSF0/GjVyR6QA3/sY25WCPL6f/y0biovk+mJ2KvPvPX26hK4DYug==
```

My signature related golang Code:

```
// get private key
bPrivateKey, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./apiclient_key.pem")
if err != nil || bPrivateKey == nil {
    log.Println(err)
    return
}
block, _ := pem.Decode(bPrivateKey)
if block == nil {
    return
}
pKeyInterface, err := x509.ParsePKCS8PrivateKey(block.Bytes)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    return
}
pKey, ok := pKeyInterface.(*rsa.PrivateKey)
if !ok {
    return
}
// sign
strForSign = "test\n"
shaForSign := sha256.New()
shaForSign.Write([]byte(strForSign))
hashedForSign := shaForSign.Sum(nil)
rawSignature, err := rsa.SignPKCS1v15(rand.Reader, pKey, crypto.SHA256, hashedForSign)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    return
}
signature := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(rawSignature)
log.Println(signature)
```

The result is as follows

```
NcW5pBmUfHqVNus1PTDjGOilazWkcyxquGc/Ldu5IAjg/gAIQOKBGp7rs8thec/THhWKjZOJtZ1Xvv85vc+bG5bB4IuCZp+wkUMgDC3kFuTPjtLEBBnlhshZ1nS0Haq5BuS6aWAF9sIz6Ulq9dLMjaOAACijwEltdOdkRo8Z5V01CZMOPM3FI0dVvTGOvXxsMvLjw3XPAxNpajXhxTTGZB5jElDkTb61U/cZ9tM+iVpd7Oo+vxvgCsrx2VhV4gURrxndj3V6Nc2iNV2bByrgw8XK1htzkqLqZpWo8JF8i5LdMrfaMukn6aikhWKFOo2icatjowiSQAAXrj9EnnrbQA==
```

apicclient_ key.pem Document content follows:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKcwggSjAgEAAoIBAQC+YVIbsE+b5Rsg
oSrcV7H21SBICjTcCKDiqEv94ghL3MfBjW5g/m9o9dcTdBpBED4NaWX+N9+aXi9o
aGNUU5Eghg1eZeFcw0utasuQnMwIc64K4L60FQxFVHjEoV0uEML7TkxMIPWh2Vdm
qyOAmBZldPBMRTXyQoqohlS0Z8z1NAwz9mVy9rnNaIgQT5FFjvfPW2dvCuvLjgo8
wqWfgJttB/8ptcUZoJU7EtPqLheEibuSDQtjGBVxttq9O6Eo3zyS2I6/0JZCRGqF
RRIqPmD2ivpI7ZwXE/cEk9R6Dv9lGZS4XZxUFpDhJnQircnH3N41nYgnFaWDm7sJ
BP9TZnkBAgMBAAECggEATumOHDYHuYnMpcjIOE8NUE/lMpcwc+gLsAesgA7Z+4AH
OL5D+2ZbjbkhLkoYu9Fctzhx8177i0PxCKkESybcaAvIrNE0CbxVuQskV8v2cqZo
hM/FnGWBEZfC+1YbhoWiHILG82NSDYVGSiMz8xCXb/R5ylOB2eolCVes8p54AUab
KU58GGFEYFMGnccy9SZ7QkG00fBLU7vJ9MINzpujujDTOS+f+MTkPpushjfUqWyj
2pfj235xajVTeHPag4Gig5wwmblu+fUxEsXtIkvM91/5GzsRVh6VIqSABhrsUXr4
zhFuiqw/ZhtYa32HnU6cpMOKIbDaHu31C0bE/CEcwQKBgQDtnEnEd8+QAuLfSsV6
wGBXV5cfnmmlkWKFxhDzW0solk9eBDKfIVw7Zw1NdanBlIrK187sOETArzeVEVFK
J4r4CnPuguTMoik5AXNAOxnA5OrYP4Tn8xk3AV9Kuh16f+CAt6zzVQQo2FXzoteK
NOlLM+oLe+XrY8kQFJkv4GXDmQKBgQDNHUVPmP2FeHbpU79mwun143HGDSPDslek
nOEv+/1Cm9+L1sla1Yglb6OZrk9wxjnw0c4HnQV5+l1K6c72ujI840BobjUqMqCW
mvb14lr/p1pVyAsSbMBlGR6EgR/QkMD/CL7KTKa/RwiM393oslvxvdGxCPuKEISN
rCt/zxLBqQKBgEHXPNmkGW/eXN9i6LXK+Oc67jVkwAGQ96v55liIw5rLi9KRdzWB
GP2c4KLGJ/PsJUlv43axYNvDsbMsyUmzC18QBm/g9WV+yc1yCW2S8t/wjuK9NybO
xf3n82/RgrmfFaaVPudud2iaCbcpOHCjmMGt8PydqGhBjkVWb9xEYe6BAoGBAIjx
/hDC6KFwaJQoIiaOBH7zOEcvBq3mKLXzODY9XD5Yq8xFv3IyFxBHlUdKJif5cT3k
Flbm830ZN6iIqnH4pwoYACy5SC3AV4+2LyTD2FXQenPDeAD5MwtM1h9JxuANhY3B
XQDcZIhY+NB1t0dhrhmczqAQi0EG/jlItlJDAxbhAoGAV5l05wHqqwEZroN0gXq2
86JTftIRzmstgs6O/yfjuInqHjMGp1fTOLyqbwA6+ZrHmzNyyoD8jiGW068LC1ue
7xucV/dYuUXUXOcX0HN/trIdMkl5jQWkrXSKP5o5ekw9gsMcicWFUBXdnJMxCcYb
i8CRH78crAdaIqZ+2buIozo=
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: Try running the `openssl` commands multiple times and comparing the outputs.

Comment: Sorry,multiple times with the same command?I do not quite get the meaning.Could you please express it some more particular?

Comment: Run your openssl command twice and compare the output. You might be surprised.

Comment: The same command I run,the same output I get, far more then twice

Comment: Check your files and commands carefully. The openssl command you show does not produce that output.

Comment: You are right,there is a wrong on the command and the output, I have mended the question.@JimB
I discover if I change the blank space in the command between `"test\n"` and `|`,the output changes, is it what you mean may surprised me?@Marc

Comment: But the problem remains, could you please help me ?

Comment: @alexdel: the typo was not the issue, there is something else wrong with your openssl command. This is not a Go problem, the openssl command should produce the same output as the Go code.

Comment: If the problem is on command, not on my go code, that would be a good news for me.

Comment: @JimB Could you please teach me how to write the command with the same output as my code of golang

Comment: I don't know what you're doing wrong, maybe it is the wrong keyname and that version of openssl errors differently, or you have another key with that name. You'll have to debug the problem.

Comment: @JimB,Thank you very much! I will check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ echo -n -e "test\n" | openssl dgst -sha256 -sign ./apiclient_key.pem | openssl base64 -A
NcW5pBmUfHqVNus1PTDjGOilazWkcyxquGc/Ldu5IAjg/gAIQOKBGp7rs8thec/THhWKjZOJtZ1Xvv85vc+bG5bB4IuCZp+wkUMgDC3kFuTPjtLEBBnlhshZ1nS0Haq5BuS6aWAF9sIz6Ulq9dLMjaOAACijwEltdOdkRo8Z5V01CZMOPM3FI0dVvTGOvXxsMvLjw3XPAxNpajXhxTTGZB5jElDkTb61U/cZ9tM+iVpd7Oo+vxvgCsrx2VhV4gURrxndj3V6Nc2iNV2bByrgw8XK1htzkqLqZpWo8JF8i5LdMrfaMukn6aikhWKFOo2icatjowiSQAAXrj9EnnrbQA==%
```

I would double check how you are running the openssl command in the shell.   Any extraneous output to stdout is going to change the signature.

I get the "NcW.." signature from both 1.0.2n-fips and openssl-3.0.0-alpha6, and from running your Go code locally.

Comment: I run the command of openssl version 1.0.2u on Windows 10 pro, maybe it makes the problem? maybe I should check it on ubuntu.